# Net Core deploying to Docker configuration

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-2.0

This is the first time I'm working with NET core, so I'm very much a newbie on that area.

Visual Studio 2017 latest update
Docker 18.03.1

I have made a project that runs fine in Visual Studio, and now want to deploy it to my local Docker.

I followed the instructions regarding build and run here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/building-net-docker-images

If I try to run the ASP.NET app locally I get this:

```
dotnet run  
C:\Users\barn\source\repos\FLG\docker-compose.dcproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.Docker.Sdk' specified could not be found.

The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.
```

However, when I download the sample application from the article, it runs fine and I can deploy to Docker and everything just works.

That led me to conclude that it is not my windows setup (paths etc) that is the reason, but my setup of the VS project.

So I looked in the Dockerfiles, but I can't find anything where the Docker sdk is specified

Theirs:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Mine:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY FLG/FLG.csproj FLG/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/FLG
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FLG.dll"]
```

I tried to alter this string

```
aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709
```

to

```
aspnetcore:2.0
```

But no difference.

EDIT:

1) I found where Microsoft.Docker.Sdk is mentioned, it is in a file that is NOT visible from VS, but I can see the file in the FileExplorer (docker-compose.dcproj)  the content is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.Docker.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectVersion>2.0</ProjectVersion>
    <DockerTargetOS>Windows</DockerTargetOS>
    <ProjectGuid>26178887-f40e-42ab-85cd-059a38097c71</ProjectGuid>
    <DockerLaunchBrowser>True</DockerLaunchBrowser>
    <DockerServiceUrl>http://{ServiceIPAddress}/api/values</DockerServiceUrl>
    <DockerServiceName>flg</DockerServiceName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="docker-compose.override.yml">
      <DependentUpon>docker-compose.yml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="docker-compose.yml" />
    <None Include=".dockerignore" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2) The sample application, does NOT have this file, in fact it does not have the "project" docker-compose at all

Comment: Aha, you learn something every day.  
While my project RAN fine, and I could step through it etc, I tried to build it, and there it failed with:  

Service XX has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.  

I'll investigate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue, described here:

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6178

It have always been an issue, and apparently there is no fix in the foreseeable future.

Anyway, thanks for the help Miq & BlackPOP

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Let me change my answer.

I think main problem for you is that you want to start your **solution** in docker by running dotnet run from cmd line. This is not the way.

I have a solution with 3 different aspnetcore apps running all together in docker and I also use dcproj to enable VS debugging in docker and it works fine.

As you found out, MS have issues with dcproj. I agree with this statement, and I found even more issues with it (i.e. if you have compose having non-aspnetcore services, there are also errors).

My solution is that to start docker services outside VisualStudio is to simply run `docker-compose up` instead `dotnet run`. If you wish to run an aspnetcore app without docker, run single project instead running whole solution.

Hope this helps you in quite difficult journey to docker+microsoft :) They have still lot of things to do and fix, so you need to be patient. It's way better than it was year ago, believe me :)

---

Docker SDK is a part of Visual Studio 2017. You need it for VS to understand .dcproj project setup. It has nothing to do with Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml files.

It's irrelevant for docker itself - it's only needed if you would like to start debug from VS an app running in docker container.

On the other hand, I remember having issues with docker SDK when I had non-standard configuration of docker-compose.yml files. Can you share them?

Comment: Curious, the sample application does not contain a docker-compose.yml file


Mine,  that is autogenerated:

    version: '3'  
    
    services:  
      flg:  
        image: flg  
        build:  
          context: .  
          dockerfile: FLG\Dockerfile

Comment: I updated my answer, see if this helps you with your work.

Answer (score 0):

Try following DockerFile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build as builder
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore \
    && dotnet publish [path to FLG].csproj -c release -o /build/publish
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /build/publish .
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://0.0.0.0:80   
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FLG.dll"]
```

Comment: No effect, when I tried to do a:

dotnet run

I got the same error as before.

I then tried to deploy:

C:\Users\barn\source\repos\FLG>docker build -t FLG .
invalid argument "FLG" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

I then tried lowercase:

C:\Users\barn\source\repos\FLG>docker build -t flg .
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx C:\Users\barn\source\repos\FLG\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.